# ¿Salto de línea en Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

No puedo hacer un salto de línea en *JavaScript*, el `\n` no me funciona, lo único que se me ocurre es hacer dos archivos *JavaScript* diferentes y usar el `<br/>`, pero me quedan muchas cosas sin poder hacer de este modo!

¿Existe algún otro método para saltar de línea en *JavaScript*?

Por ejemplo, de este modo no me funciona.

```js
var nombreabuelo = "Juan"
var nombreabuela = "María"
document.write(
  "El nombre de tu abuelo es: " + nombreabuelo + "\nEl nombre de tu abuela es: " + nombreabuela
)
```

He leído en todos los foros y todos dicen que el salto de línea es `\n`. Incluso también he leido que con `<b/>` funciona, pero esto me lo coloca en negrita.

Comment: ya has intentado con un `\n\r` ?

Comment: Ahora lo intento!

Comment: Estas bien, utiliza el `<br>` pero sin la diagonal. La diagonal en el <br> es para html

Comment: explica tu respuesta por favor, que tiene que ver la diagonal? o si nos indicas una fuente donde consultar tu afirmación

Comment: pues, lo acabo de probar, estoy imprimiendo resultados con `document.write` , en el texto que insertas en la linea le pudes poner la `<br>` y funciona perfectamente, o si lo quieres hacer mas prolijo, lo concatenas con `+ "<br>"` a tu linea que vas a imprimir y funciona el salto de linea, no podria poner una fuente de donde exactamente lo se, pero lo estoy aplicando en este momento. saludos!

Comment: lo sé sin embargo yo lo he probado con `<br /> ` es decir usando la diagonal y tambien sirve por eso te hice la observación+

Comment: ah ok, no hay problema, funciona de ambos modos, solo que como el que formulo la pregunta comento que ya lo habia hecho de esa manera, solo  daba un apcion mas que probar, es todo, pero tienes razon, funciona tambien con diagonal.

Answer (score 8):

El problema que tienes es un poco de conceptos.

El caracter `\n`, es el usado en javascript, para realizar el sato de línea, mientras que el `<br>`, es el usado en `HTML`

Al querer hacer un `document.write`, lo que estas haciendo es escribir `HTML`, para lo cual, debes usar `<br>`.

Otra cosa sería que quisieras usar un `alert`, para lo cual si deberías usar el `\n`.

Solo debes pensar en donde vas a representar el texto, para saber que caracter usar

Answer (score 3):

Debes hacerlo de la forma `html`:

```
var nombreabuelo = "mario";
var nombreabuela = "maria";
document.write("El nombre de tu abuelo es: " + nombreabuelo + "<br/>El nombre de tu abuela es: " + nombreabuela);
```

usando la etiqueta `<br/>`

Comment: Oh gracias, crei que no iba a funcionar en el archivo de javascript.

Answer (score 1):

#### Salto de línea en Javascript.

Debido a que estas usando el método

> [document.write()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/write): El método escribe expresiones HTML o código
> JavaScript en un documento.

En realidad tratas de representar un salto de linea en HTML, para esto puedes usar el elemento [**`<br>` (Line break)**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/br) que indica un salto de linea:

```js
var nombreabuelo = "Juan"
var nombreabuela = "María"
document.write(
  "El nombre de tu abuelo es: " + nombreabuelo + "<br>" + "El nombre de tu abuela es: " + nombreabuela
)
```

Es incorrecto usar para esto `<b/>` , ya que esto sirve para indicar caracteres en formato bold y no para indicar una nueva línea, revisa este ejemplo.

```js
    var nombreabuelo = "Juan"
    var nombreabuela = "María"
    document.write(
      "El nombre de tu abuelo es: <b>" + nombreabuelo + "</b> " + "El nombre de tu abuela es:<b> " + nombreabuela + "</b>")
```

---

En el caso de `Javascript`, por ejemplo si deseas realizarlo en la consola, lo realizarias usando `\n`, que indica una nueva linea:

```js
var nombreabuelo = "Juan"
var nombreabuela = "María"
console.log(
  "El nombre de tu abuelo es: " + nombreabuelo + "\n" + "El nombre de tu abuela es: " + nombreabuela
)
```

Answer (score 0):

document.write te permite escribir en el DOM de la pagina web en la que estés.

Si quieres realizar un salto de linea puedes hacerlo mediante `<br />`

```
document.write("El nombre de tu abuelo es: " + nombreabuelo + "<br />El nombre de tu abuela es: " + nombreabuela)
```

Answer (score 0):

Utiliza `<br/>` en vez de `\n` y/o `\r`

```js
var nombreabuelo = 'abuelito';
var nombreabuela = 'abuelita';

document.querySelector('p').innerHTML = `El nombre de tu abuelo es: ${nombreabuelo}<br/>
El nombre de tu abuela es: ${nombreabuela}`;
```

```html
<p></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

utilizando `<br>` y `EcmaScript2015` para formatear el texto.

```js
var nombreAbuelo = "Juan"
var nombreAbuela = "María"
document.write(
  `El nombre de tu abuelo es: ${nombreAbuelo}<br> El nombre de tu abuela es: ${nombreAbuela}`
)
```